# Basic pointers and arrays for C standard

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Hi
I had to make a program using pointers for a lab in C language. The said I must use pointers as a parameter (I know arrays are pointers I just use functions to have to make the teacher happy).

In short, I have to make two methods, one to display how many characters of a given letter occur in a character array and output the results as an average and for each time it occurs print a '*' beside it.

The problem is that I am getting funky numbers on my display.
Sorry for the formatting, not sure how to get it properly on here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char Ar[] = "alot of words here";


void getFrequency(char*, int*);
void displayVHist(char*, int*);

int main (void){

int ABStats[26], i, *pABS;
char Alphabet[26] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N', 'O',  'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'Y', 'X', 'Z'};
char *pAr = Ar, *pA = Alphabet;
pABS = ABStats;

for (i=0;i<26;i++){
    ABStats[i] = 0; 
}//end for

getFrequency(pAr, pABS);
displayVHist(pA, pABS);


}//end main

void getFrequency(char *ar1, int *ar2){

int letter;

while(*ar1 != '\0'){

    letter = isalpha(*ar1)?(toascii(toupper(*ar1))-'A'):-1;

     if(letter != -1){
         *(ar2 + letter) += 1;       
     }//end if
     ++ar1;
 }//end while
}//end function

 void displayVHist(char *ar1, int *ar2){

 double average;
 int i, j, total;

for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
     total += *ar2;
    ++ar2;
}//end for

for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    average =  ((double)(*ar2)/total)*100;
    printf("'%c' (%lf) ",*ar1 ,average);
    for(j=0;j=*ar2;j++){
        printf("*");        
    }//end 
    printf("\n");
    ++ar1;
    ++ar2;
}//end for
}//end
```

Comment: _I know arrays are pointers I just use functions to have to make the teacher happy_ - You seem to know it all! If you cannot listen to your teacher, will what we say matter?

Comment: Actually, pointers and arrays are not the same thing!

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

Comment: "I know arrays are pointers" Who told you that? That's just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `displayVHist` function you have two loops. Both uses, and modifies the `ar2` variable. When the first loop is done, the `ar2` variable no longer points to what was passed in the call to the function.

To solve this, you can use a local variable for the first (or second) loop. If you use a local variable for the second loop, just remember to initialize it *before* the first loop.

---

And as others have noted, arrays are *not* the same as pointer. However, since arrays decays to pointers (for example, when you pass an array as an argument to a function, the function receives a pointer to the first entry of the array) you can use pointer arithmetic on an array. And the opposite is true as well, you can use array indexing with a pointer.

So, for example, the expression `*(ar2 + letter)` is equal to `ar2[letter]`.